# Как сделать таймер с параметрами?

Tags: c#

```
public class MyTimerData
{
    public int delay { get; set; }
    public string parameter { get; set; }
}

    class ex_program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<MyTimerData> MyTimers = new List<MyTimerData>();
            MyTimers.Add(new MyTimerData());
            MyTimers.Last().delay = 1000;
            MyTimers.Last().parameter = "AVS";


            MyTimers.Add(new MyTimerData());
            MyTimers.Last().delay = 5000;
            MyTimers.Last().parameter = "4658sss";


            foreach (var t in MyTimers)
            {
                var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(t.delay);
                timer.Elapsed += OnTimeout;
                timer.AutoReset = true;
                timer.Enabled = true;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Идет запись . . .");
            Console.WriteLine("Нажмите ENTER что бы выйти из программы");
            Console.Read();
        }


        static void OnTimeout(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            var str = new[] { ((MyTimers)sender).Parameter.ToString() };
            string path = @"c:\пример.txt"; if (!File.Exists(path))
                File.WriteAllLines(path, str);
            else
                File.AppendAllLines(path, str);

        }
    }
}
```

У меня ошибка

```
(MyTimers) => var str = new[] { ((MyTimers)sender).Parameter.ToString() };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У этой проблемы есть два варианта решения:

1) Через связку Ключ-Значение, можно использовать Dictionary или KeyValuePair. Но это будет не очень красиво, по моему мнению.

2) Создать свой таймер, пример кода ниже.

```
public class MyTimer : System.Timers.Timer {
    public object Parameter { get; set; }
}
static void Main(string[] args) {
    List<MyTimer> MyTimers = new List<MyTimer>();
    MyTimers.Add(new MyTimer());
    MyTimers.Last().Interval = 1000;
    MyTimers.Last().Parameter = "AVS";

    MyTimers.Add(new MyTimer());
    MyTimers.Last().Interval = 5000;
    MyTimers.Last().Parameter = "4658sss";

    foreach(var timer in MyTimers) {
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimeout;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Идет запись . . .");
    Console.WriteLine("Нажмите ENTER что бы выйти из программы");
    Console.Read();
}
static void OnTimeout(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    var str = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).Parameter.ToString() };
    string path = @"c:\пример.txt"; if(!File.Exists(path))
        File.WriteAllLines(path, str);
    else
        File.AppendAllLines(path, str);
}
```

Comment: почему у меня ошибка?

Comment: все работает!!! Спасибо))